# Validation based on user entered data

Tags: excel, forms, vba, validation, vlookup

I'm attempting to create a form for data entry of lab results, which validates an answer based on the specification of the product tested. The user enters the following information: Product Code and SG result etc

My source data is a table with 4 columns,
Product Code, Description, SG low, SG high

SOURCE

[image: Source data]

When the user enters the Product Code and SG in the form I would like it to validate based on the specific range allowed for that product (from the source data), and have a dialogue box asking the user to reconsider the result entered (if it were outside of the range).

Easy enough to flag with conditional formatting in the results sheet, but I don't want my users to have access to it.

RESULTS

[image: Results with out of spec flag]

I need to refer to separate Range VLOOKUP to return the specs.

THE FORM
[image: the user entry form]

Thanks in advance!

*(update)*

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value <> ""
i = i + 1
Wend

Dim losg, loph, hisg, hiph As Double
losg = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ProdCode.Text, Sheet1.Range("A1:F24"), 3, False)
hisg = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ProdCode.Text, Sheet1.Range("A1:F24"), 4, False)
loph = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ProdCode.Text, Sheet1.Range("A1:F24"), 5, False)
hiph = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ProdCode.Text, Sheet1.Range("A1:F24"), 6, False)


If SGresult.Text < losg Then
MsgBox "SG result " & SGresult.Text & " too low"
ElseIf SGresult.Text > hisg Then
MsgBox "SG result " & SGresult.Text & " too high"
Else: MsgBox "SG result " & SGresult.Text & " just right"
End If
If pHresult.Text < loph Then
MsgBox "ph result " & pHresult.Text & " too low"
ElseIf pHresult.Text > hiph Then
MsgBox "ph result " & pHresult.Text & " too high"
Else: MsgBox "ph result " & phresult.Text & " just right"
End If

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value = ProdCode.Value 'Enter Code in Column A
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i).Value = BNenter.Value 'Enter BN in Column C
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & i).Value = DOMenter.Value 'Enter DOM in Column D
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & i).Value = SGresult.Value 'Enter SG result in Column E
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F" & i).Value = pHresult.Value 'Enter pH result in Column F
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K" & i).Value = BatcherID.Value 'Enter Batcher ID in Column K

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want the form accept result even though it is outside the range?

Comment: Hi @AdityaPansare, I do want to accept an out of range result, but have the pop up suggest to the user that they check their result (I might add a comment box to the form if they want to explain).

Comment: I need to use VLOOKUP because the range of acceptable values is different depending on the product

Comment: @Steamroller60, is _"the form "_ a worksheet?

Comment: Hi Steamroller60 please check the edited version.

Comment: Hi @user3598756, the form is a VBA form (image now in edited question). I wish to use the form to keep the user separate from the data store.

Comment: @Steamroller60, then show your userform code so that we can be more effective in helping you

Answer (score 1):

Save Products in column "K" and valid result for respective product in column "L". Below code will give you desired output

```
Dim result, prod As String
Dim rng As Range

result = Val(resultText.Value)
prod = prodText.Value

ActiveSheet.Activate
On Error GoTo step:
Set rng = Range("K:K").Find(What:=prod, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If rng.Offset(0, 1).Value <> result Then

    MsgBox "The result entered is out of valid range!"

End If

Exit Sub

step:
MsgBox "Invalid Product"
Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**edited** after OP clarified the "form" was a "UserFom"

You may want to check user input while he/she's editing/exiting any control instead of waiting for the `CommandButton1_Click` event and check them all together

Such a "modular" approach should keep code more easy to control and maintain

For example the `TextBox`  `Exit` event could be used to check the user input as he/she's leaving it and have him/her come back to it in case of wrong input

Moreover

- since "Product Code" must be chosen between those listed in "Source" worksheet column "A"

  you may want to use a `ComboBox` control and have the user choose one out of a list
- since "Product Name" must be the one corresponding to the chosen "Product Code"

  you may want to use a `Label` control and have the user simply *looks* at what name corresponds to the product code he just chose

Following what above and assuming "ProductNameLbl" as the label name, your userform code could be something like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.ProdCodeCB.List = GetSourceData(1) '<--| fill Product Name combobox list with "Source" worksheet column 1 data
End Sub


Private Sub ProdCodeCB_Change() '<--| fires when the user change the combobox selection
    Me.ProdNameLbl.Caption = Worksheets("Source").Cells(Me.ProdCodeCB.ListIndex + 2, 2) '<--| update Product Name label with the name corresponding to the chosen Product Code
End Sub


Private Sub SGresultTB_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean) '<--| fires upon exiting the SGresult textbox
    Dim msgErr As String

    With Me '<--| reference the Userform
        If .ProdCodeCB.ListIndex <> -1 Then '<--| if a valid selection has been made in 'ProductCode' combobox
            If Not IsValueInRange(.SGresultTB, GetProdCodeRange(.ProdCodeCB.ListIndex + 1), msgErr) Then '<-- if value out of range then...
                With .SGresultTB
                    MsgBox "SG value " & .Value & msgErr _
                        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please reconsider the value you input in 'SG' texbox"
                    Cancel = True
                    .SetFocus '<--| get the user back to the textbox
                    ' following two lines select the textbox text so that the user can delete it
                    .SelStart = 0
                    .SelLength = Len(.Text)
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub

'-------------------------------------------------
' helper functions
'---------------------------
Function GetSourceData(colIndex As Long)
    ' this function returns an array with "Source" worksheets data in passed column from its row 2 to last not empty one
    With Worksheets("Source") '<--| reference "Source" worksheet
        GetSourceData = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(2, colIndex), .Cells(.Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp)).Value)
    End With
End Function

Function IsValueInRange(tb As MSForms.TextBox, rangeArr As Variant, msgErr As String) As Boolean
    ' this function returns a boolean (true/false) with the result of the checking whether the passed texbox (tb) text exceeds the passed range (rangeArr)
    ' msgErr is also set to some text if the range is exceeded
    With tb
        Select Case CDbl(.Value) '<-- prepare to act accordingly to its value
            Case Is < rangeArr(1) '<--| if it's smaller than "SG Low" value
                msgErr = " is lower than 'SG Low' = " & rangeArr(1) '<-- build the final part of the error message correspondingly
            Case Is > rangeArr(2) '<--| while if it's greater than "SG High" value
                msgErr = " is greater than 'SG High' = " & rangeArr(2) '<-- build the final part of the error message correspondingly
        End Select
    End With
    IsValueInRange = msgErr = ""
End Function

Function GetProdCodeRange(iProd As Long)
    ' this function returns an array of the SG minimum and maximum values in "Source" worksheet corresponding to the chosen product
    With Worksheets("Source") '<--| reference "Source" worksheet
        With .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column "A" cels from row 2 down to last not empty one
            GetProdCodeRange = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Cells(iProd, 1).Offset(, 2).Resize(, 2).Value)) '<--| return an array with "SG low" and "SG high" values corresponding to the product index passed
        End With
    End With
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------
```

as you may see, I named controls after the names you chose for them except for adding a suffix to tell what kind of control they are:

- ProdCodeCB: "CB" -> it's a `ComboBox` control name
- SGresultTB: "TB" -> it's a `TextBox` control name
- ProdNameLbl: "Lbl" -> it's a `Label` control name